# Blender to unity fbx export comes out destroyed

Tags: animation, export, transforms, .fbx

So the problem is as follows, I got a model with a rig and animations attached and just saving it as .blend and opening it in Unity works wonders, but when exporting to FBX hell happens.

The model shrinks and goes upside down, and animations dont work. Exporting to OBJ seems to be fine but animations can't be exported on obj. so that wont work.

I'm not sure if its fine to continue using .blend files on a project we're going to port on android? Anyway its somewhat pain in the ass since it requires everyone on the team to have blender installed.

Any clues?

[image]

[image]

In the second image the crouching one is .blend and the messed up one is .fbx.

I've also applied scale and everything, and tries "Experimental apply transform" on fbx export but it didnt seem to do anything.

Answer (score 2):

In Blender:

- Important step: First in the *Dopesheet*, *Action Editor* tab, before you do your animation you have to name it accordingly and hit little *F* icon there to add a Fake user otherwise the animation is not being saved when you close Blender.

[image]

-Then you select the mesh itself and the armature that you want to export. Go to Export option in File/Export/FBX

-You can see the option for 'Export BFX' at the bottom-left corner, leave everything as default only check the 'Selected Objects' checkbox. Also choose only Armature and Mesh to export down below.

[image]

In Unity:

-Select the FBX file in the *Project* panel that you just imported in (I assumed you already know how to import it in)

-In the *Inspector* panel:

1. with *Model* make sure scale factor is 1.

[image]

2. in <kbd>Rig</kbd> make sure Animation Type is Humanoid for your character. If it is a thing or anything not full body human, pretty much choose Generic.

[image]

3. <kbd>Animations</kbd> down below at Anim. Compression. Choose Optimal.

[image]

Now anything left is to create animation controller and assign animations to the character :) If this does not work or I'm not clear in any step, please don't hesitate to leave a comment so I can help you. Goodluck!